# Redirect all 404 Errors to my index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I recently just rebuilt my site from Wordpress to Rails 3.2.6. My naming conventions for articles and such have changed, as a result a lot of links around the web pointing to my site are giving 404 errors.

How can I redirect all 404 errors back to my index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails 3 you can redirect everything that is not matched by previous route rules by placing a catch-all route at the end of your config/routes.rb file, like so:

```
match "/*other" => redirect("/")
```